# Test if any of the results in an array have a value in a particular node

Tags: php, arrays, testing

Here is a fun issue I am wrestling with. I have a Multi Dimensional array:

This should return true

```
array(
    array('id' = > 23, 'address' => '123 Grove Street, Toronto'),
    array('id' = > 24, 'address' => ''),
    array('id' = > 25, 'address' => ''),
    array('id' = > 26, 'address' => '123 Grove Street, Toronto')
)
```

This should return false

```
array(
    array('id' = > 23, 'address' => ''),
    array('id' = > 24, 'address' => ''),
    array('id' = > 25, 'address' => ''),
    array('id' = > 26, 'address' => '')
)
```

I want to test the above array to see if ANY of the the results have a value in the address field.  So the first example would return TRUE but below would return false.  The usage is for an element that will only appear when there are results with addresses.

Comment: Thanks Tim.  Code indents were not taking for some reason.

Comment: So if any of the arrays have a non-empty `'address'` then the function should return true, otherwise false.  Am I understanding correctly?

Comment: This should be fairly trivial. I can understand not knowing how to do it but what have you tried?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function hasAtLeastOneAddress($arr)
{
    foreach($arr as $subarr)
    {
        if($subarr['address'] != '')
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```